# How to convert struct with recursive array to class in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert (map) a struct that has a recursive array into a class.

```
// converting from
struct PersonStruct {
  let name: String
  let children: [PersonStruct]?
}

// to
class PersonClass {
  let name: String
  let children: [PersonClass]?
}

// I tried this, 1. create person struct (John has a child John Jr whom has a child John Jr II)
let someone = PersonStruct(name: "John", children: [PersonStruct(name: "John Jr.", children: [Product(name: "John Jr. II", children: [])])]

// 2. map that struct to class model
let somebodyChildren: PersonClass = someone.children.map { child in
   PersonClass(name: child.name, children: child.children) // I'm stuck here, this is wrong
}

let somebody = PersonClass(name: someone.name, children: somebodyChildren)
```

I can't figure out how to map a recursive array.. any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The key detail is to implement a recursive class constructor. Classes, unlike structs, must either have a constructor (the `init` method) or else use `var` instead of `let` for property declarations. In order to keep the class' properties immutable as in your example, I kept the declarations with `let` and defined two `init` methods to do the struct-to-class conversion. The "normal" initializer can also construct `PersonClass` instances directly, without needing a corresponding `PersonStruct`.

**Working version (I tested it):**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // I tried this, 1. create person struct (John has a child John Jr whom has a child John Jr II)
        // Note that you might want to use nil for PersonStructs with no children's 'children' property, not an empty array.
        // It's an Optional array of PersonStructs, not an array of Optional PersonStructs.
        let someone = PersonStruct(name: "John", children: [PersonStruct(name: "John Jr.", children: [PersonStruct(name: "Bob", children: [PersonStruct(name: "Alice", children: nil)]), PersonStruct(name: "John Jr. II", children: nil)])])
        
        // Construct 'somebody' from the same struct literal as was used for 'someone'
        let somebody = PersonClass(from: PersonStruct(name: "John", children: [PersonStruct(name: "John Jr.", children: [PersonStruct(name: "Bob", children: [PersonStruct(name: "Alice", children: nil)]), PersonStruct(name: "John Jr. II", children: nil)])]))
        
        // Construct 'someoneElse' from the 'someone' PersonStruct (result should be equivalent)
        let someoneElse = PersonClass(from: someone)
        
        print("someone's name is \(somebody.name) and his child is \(somebody.children![0].name) and his grandchildren are named \(somebody.children![0].children![0].name) and \(somebody.children![0].children![1].name) and his great-grandchild is \(somebody.children![0].children![0].children![0].name)")
        print("someoneElse's name is \(someoneElse.name) and his child is \(someoneElse.children![0].name) and his grandchildren are named \(someoneElse.children![0].children![0].name) and \(someoneElse.children![0].children![1].name) and his great-grandchild is \(somebody.children![0].children![0].children![0].name)")
    }
    
    // converting from
    /* OP's Comment:
       "The reason I'm doing this mapping from struct to class is because
       the struct model is used to decode the API reponse,
       while the class model is used by the UI.
       I did not want to use the API model directly in the UI"
    */
    struct PersonStruct {
        let name: String
        let children: [PersonStruct]?
    }

    // to
    class PersonClass {
        let name: String
        let children: [PersonClass]?
        
        // Normal initializer (for constructing instances directly, and also for use inside the recursive initializer as a base case)
        init(name: String, children: [PersonClass]?) {
            self.name = name
            self.children = children
        }
        
        // Special initializer (for constructing class instances based on PersonStruct instances)
        init(from: PersonStruct) {
            self.name = from.name
                
            // Map function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/map(_:)-87c4d
            /*
             The nested ternary expression first checks whether the struct's children array is nil.
             Only if it isn't, it then evaluates whether each PersonStruct in that array has its own children,
             and calls the simple constructor if it doesn't and the recursive constructor if it does.
            */
            self.children = (from.children == nil) ? nil : (from.children!).map { ($0.children == nil) ? PersonClass(name: $0.name, children: nil) : PersonClass(from: $0) }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I made some slight changes to your original code, like using `nil` instead of an empty array for `PersonStructs` with no children. Also, I made the `PersonStruct` instance in the demonstration more complex, to show that the recursive class constructor can handle arrays of arbitrary depth.

---

This answer is a collaboration with another contributor, Alexander, who suggested several optimizations to the original code. The original code can be seen in the edit history. Refer to his answer for a way to consolidate the initializers and remove the nested ternary operator.

Comment: You can simplify your `for` loop into just a call to `map`

Comment: Oh and there's a trick to not needing to write your first initializer. As you knows, the compiler will automatically synthesize a memberwise initializer for classes, but it won't do so if you provide any explicit initializers yourself. There's a neat workaround: define your initializer in an `extension` (rather than in the main `class` declaration), and the memberwise initializer will be preserved in addition to your custom one.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know that was possible. Doesn't the memberwise initializer require that `let` be changed to `var` though? As soon as I had pasted OP's question code into my project, I got that `Class 'ViewController.PersonClass' has no initializers` error.

Comment: @Alexander Are you interested in adding your own answer to this question? I don't want to edit mine to use `map` as it's not something I would have thought of on my own. OP hasn't accepted anything yet so you could still get the checkmark!

Comment: If my code is using "let" instead of "var" by mistake, I can change it to "var" in the class. Also, the reason I'm doing this mapping from struct to class is because the struct model is used to decode the API reponse, while the class model is used by the UI. I did not want to use the API model directly in the UI.

Comment: @VanDuTran I wouldn't call using `let` a 'mistake': it's just a different way of doing things. Thanks for adding the clarification on why you're converting the struct instances to class instances!

Comment: "as it's not something I would have thought of on my own" That's ok, you can just edit it in anyway. It's not some particularly novel idea I'm introducing, and it doesn't really warrant a separate nearly-identical-but-slightly-different answer. I don't really care for the points/checkmarks

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Try to stay away from bifurcating your answer with multiple variants, unless those variants each have their own benefits. Imagine the perspective of a coming reader, who might be confused which one they should use. "If the `map` variant is better, why are they also showing `for`? Why wouldn't I want the `map` variant?". Also you can inline `temp` and just assign the new array directly to `self.children`.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure what you meant by "inline" temp? I rewrote it to get rid of temp and the optional binding by using a nested ternary instead. The outer layer checks for `nil` and the inner layer (inside `map`) determines which initializer to call. I removed the original code as you suggested.

Comment: @Alexander That was a nice catch noticing that `temp` is no longer necessary. I had it at first because the array was built incrementally by the `for` loop, but using `map` allows the same result to be assigned 'all at once.' It hadn't registered on me that this change removed the reason for having the temporary variable in the first place.

Comment: Haha I think you got it, but took the time to write up an answer so you see what I mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/76901025/3141234 Notice that the "special" initializer delegates to the memberwise one. With classes, that's usually a good idea, it's nice to have all initialization funnel into one common init, where common logic can be centralized

Answer (score 1):

You need some recursion, because transforming one `PersonStruct` into a `PersonClass` requires you to also transform its `children`.

```
extension PersonClass {
    convenience init(from source: PersonStruct) {
        let newChildren: [PersonClass]?
        if let children = source.children {
            // This recurses to build the new child objects in the same manner as the parent.
            newChildren = children.map { PersonClass(from: $0) }
        } else {
            newChildren = nil
        }

        self.init(name: source.name, children: newChildren)
    }
}
```

The type of `children` being `[ParentStruct]?` is a bit odd. Optional collections have their place (e.g. sometimes you might need to distinguish between "unset" and "set and empty"), but where possible, try to avoid that and just use an empty array. If you can get away with that, then this code simplifies even more:

```swift
extension PersonClass {
    convenience init(from source: PersonStruct) {
        self.init(
            name: source.name,
            children: source.children.map { PersonClass(from: $0) }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Good call, those were oversights, I typed this up on my phone without running it haha

Comment: I like how compact the second version is, especially since OP seemed to be using empty arrays to represent `PersonClass` instances with no children (instead of `nil`). In my version, I had replaced the empty arrays with `nil` but hadn't considered the alternative.

Comment: @Alexander yes, if empty array is the better practice then I can use thet instead of optional.

Comment: There are definitely good uses of optional collections (like a mentioned, to distinguish “not yet set” to “set already, but empty”), but if you don’t need to make that distinction in your domain, it’s better to use empty.

Comment: Two things with the 2nd implementation: I think we need convenience keyword too, and I get this error: Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation

Comment: @VanDuTran You can suggest an edit directly, btw :) As for the type error: are you sure you have an initializer like `PersonClass.init(name:children:)`?